# Maven does not know my internal project

Tags: java, maven, build, project-management

I have two projects A and B managed with maven and B depends on A. (Additionally they both have external dependencies from the public repositories).

When I run `mvn compile` on A everything is ok.
When I run `mvn compile` on B it tells me `1 required artifact is missing`.

Doing mvn install on A does not help. What should I do?

I should add that these are two different projects rather than two modules of 1 project. Help.

**UPDATE**
It was just a typo in the referencing `pom.xml`, which I discovered thanks to @Raghuram's comment

Comment: Are you sure your version reference from B <parent> matches A version?

Comment: Can you post the relevant pom snippets from A and B?  Also relevant portion of the maven run - lines around the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `mvn install` should be enough - check there are no typos in your `pom.xml` files.

Answer (score 0):

Either [install it manually](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) to your local repository or use a repository manager like [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/).

Comment: What is the difference between your first suggestion and doing `mvn install`?

Answer (score 0):

I would, as Rohan mentions as a comment to your question, create a parent pom you can execute the install goal for, including your two "internal" projects as modules.

Comment: There is no parent pom. Why should there be?

Comment: Read the section on Project inheritance: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html